# Weird space above first zsh prompt

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I tried to use someone else’s ZSH config. It added a newline before the first prompt. I didn’t like it and switched to spaceship, but it still lingers. Here’s the image:
[image: Space before prompt]

Any ideas? I don’t have any prompt newline config in my zshrc.

Comment: What does `echo ${(Q)prompt}` say?

Comment: It outputs $(spaceship_prompt)

Comment: And how is the function (or program, or alias) `spaceship_prompt` defined? Further, what does echo `${(Q)$(spaceship_prompt)}` say?

Comment: It prints: %{%B%}%{%b%}%{%B%F{cyan}%(4~||)%3~%{%b%f%}%{%B%} %{%b%} %{%B%}%{%b%}%{%B%F{green}%}> %{%b%f%}%{%B%}%{%b%}

Comment: I find the prompt odd in that it contains elements which don't seem to generate actual output (such as the conditional `%(4~||)` where both the true and the false part are empty), but I don't see anything which would generated newlines. Could it be that your `TERM` variable is set incorrectly? The prompt outputs escape strings (for instance for bold face and colours), and if your terminal can not handle them, it might result in printing newlines.